# Best practice for conditional form elements with database unique ID reliance

Tags: javascript, html, forms, laravel-5

I am working on a form with a number of conditional fields, which are hidden or revealed depending on check boxes, which themselves come from items in a table.

The checkboxes look like this

```
@foreach ($media as $medium)
        <div class="col-4 col-md-auto form-check form-check-inline media-checkbox-group required">
            <input class="form-check-input media-checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="media[{{ $medium->id }}]" value="{{ $medium->id }}" id="mediumId{{ $medium->id }}">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ $medium->id }}">{{ $medium->type }}</label>
        </div>
@endforeach
```

my javascript function like this

```
$('#mediumId3').on("change", function () {
  var x = document.getElementById("block");
  if (this.checked) {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

and my html form element like this

```
<div id="block" style="display:none;">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="poemCount" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Require this many poems') }}</label>

    <div class="col-md-8">

      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="mr-1" for="countMin">{{ __('Min:') }}</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="countMin" name="countMin">
          <option value=""> -- </option>
          @foreach ($numbers as $number)
            <option value="{{ $number }}" {{$number == old("countMin") ? "selected": ""}}>{{ $number }}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Everything works fine and the element toggles on and off display as expected, but my question is this.

I'm worried that since the javascript relies on the medium unique id being '3', if this is ever changed (perhaps by an accidental deletion and replacement), the form will stop working.
Is it ok to rely on database IDs for this sort of function? Is there a more robust way of doing it?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Do you want only id 3 to  appear in `#mediumId3` or all ids? and what determines the id to track its changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the selector more reliable by using the class `.media-checkboxes` and  looping its items. Then you can extract and check the id

```
$( ".media-checkboxes" ).each(function( index ) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id"); // you can extract 'name' or 'value'
    //if you want, you can check this id and only 
    //listen to the event for a certain item.
    $('#' + id).on("change", function () {
    var x = document.getElementById("block");
    if (this.checked) {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
});
```

This code tends to inspire you to gain more control over this.